# disable tooltip for iframe loaded by tinymce plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I am working with 2 different projects which will be integrated during deployment. In my project A I'm having `bootstrap` and `jquery ui` libraries.
In my project B I don't have any references to them.

Always Project B will give a html view which will be appended within the html of Project A.

Coming to the problem, I'm loading a `tinymce` plugin from my project B, which in turn gives the response within an `iframe`. This iframe has some `title`. This title is being used by the `jquery ui` tooltip function, to display tooltip for this iframe on hover. Since this is a library file I do not prefer to change/remove the title. I tried removing the title after loading the tinymce. Also I tried `

> .tooltip('disable')

&

> .tooltip('destroy')

But whatever I do, the tooltip appears for the very first time on screen. How to disable this completely is what I want. And this tinymce is opened on a button click. So I couldn't remove title or disable tooltip on page load as well. I've spent more than 2 days on this issue and couldn't figure out a solution.

PFB the html structure of my iframe. I've just given empty head & body tags below since I can't copy the whole iframe content.

```
> <iframe title="{#aria.rich_text_area}Press ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press
> ALT-0 for help" id="Notes_ifr" src='javascript:""' frameborder="0"
> style="width: 100%; height: 100px; display: block;"
> allowtransparency="true"><html><head></head><body></body></html></iframe>
```

Comment: We need to see more code.

Comment: @PalinDrome555 I've edited my question. Please let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the title and hide the tooltip with following code.

```
$("#Notes_ifr").removeAttr("title");
$("#Notes_ifr").removeAttr("data-original-title");
$("#Notes_ifr").tooltip('hide');
```

Comment: Yes I did try this. There is a peculiar scenario in which this fix fails. When my iframe opens at the place where my cursor is already present, then the jquery tooltip function executes before the above statements. So tooltip gets displayed for the very first time.

Comment: Do u have it somewhere online?